# How do I make sure my formula's are only in cells with input?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I currently have a formula that copies the cells from a certain column to a new column. It looks like this:

```
=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!B9:B1048576;1;0)=0;"";INDEX(Sheet1!B9:B1048576;1;0))
```

And what I did was copy this formula to the entire column:

```
C6:C1048576
```

The reason why I need this is that I don't know how big the data on sheet 1 will be. The problem with this is, that it makes my excel really slow because it keeps calculating all these millions of unused cells. So I am looking for a way to avoid copying my formulas across millions of cells.

I was thinking that maybe I can create a function that counts the amount of cells with text and based on this I can insert my formulas only for. But I can't seem to find a way how to do this.

Maybe there is even a simpler way to copy the cells from one column to a new one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just copying a column, why do you need `index`? You can replace `=index(B9:B1234567896,1,0)` with `=B9`.

In fact, you should be able to write `=B:B` - if you write this in cell A42, it will look up B42, for example.

(Give `B:B` a name and you can make things even clearer: `=cust_email` for example.)

If you really need `index`, try `=index(…)&""` instead of `=if(index(…)=0,"",index(…))`, if you're removing `0`s where `index` copies an empty cell. (This will turn numbers to text.)

I don't have a good answer for the "keep the formulas synced with the data" problem. (I've never touched VBA but there'll be something in there.) You could try having 10,000 rows of formulas and a warning function which alerts you if the 10,001st data row isn't blank? Or a warning function which counts for non-blanks in the formula column and in a data column and alerts you if there's more data rows than formula rows?

Comment: Thanks for the input!

I changed the following:


=IF(INDEX(Sheet1!B3:B1000;1;0)=0; "";INDEX(Sheet1!B3:B1000;1;0))

To:

 IF(Sheet1!B:B=0; "";Sheet1!B:B).

And my solution is to just limit my formulas to the first 1000 rows, because I don't expect files with more rows then that and this way excel still runs smooth.